# How to kill another function

Tags: javascript, vk

I have a function that does request to API when the video is finished:

```
 video.addEventListener('ended', example);
 var example = function () {
   VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function(data) { 
     /**...*/ 
   }
 }
```

And also I have a replay button (shows when video is finished), which the user can click faster than the response comes from API. And now I need to kill my function. How I can do it?

Link to API: https://vk.com/dev/video.get

Comment: What is the criteria? I mean, you have to kill the function whenever the user clicks on the replay button?

Comment: How is made the call to API? Ajax call? then you can use `xhr.abort();` after removing the event listeners

Comment: You may want to take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137656/how-to-stop-a-javascript-function-from-within-another-function . as @Kaiido said, it actually depends on what that .api function does.

Comment: @briosheje yes, replay button shows when video is finished.

Comment: @Kaiido I do this `VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function(data) {  }` and get response.

Comment: what is `VK`? which api does it call?

Comment: @Kaiido https://vk.com/dev/video.get

Comment: Ok, your best bet is to ask them directly if there is a cancel method (maybe [here](http://vk.com/apiclub) but I don't read russian), or to set a boolean flag to true while making the call and to false when asking for replay

Comment: what return `VK.api` function?

Comment: @Grundy response in JSON, like this (bottom of page): https://vk.com/dev/video.get

Comment: @pertpoert i mean what output if you do `console.log(VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function(data) { 
     /**...*/ 
   })`

Answer (score 0):

There don't seems to be any method to cancel a all from this api.
So either you analyse the code to see how is handled that call (Can't do it for you because we need an auth).

I'd say that your best bet is to set a boolean flag to true while making the call and to false when asking for replay :

```js
//Our flag
var userCanceledCalled = false;
var example = function () {
  document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = "new example should be called in few seconds";
    //Set it to fals at call
 userCanceledCalled = false;
 VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function(data) { 
     if(!userCanceledCalled){
       alert(data);
     }
   });
 }
 
 function replay(){
   //Set it to true on user action
 document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = "new example as been canceled";
  userCanceledCalled = true;
  }

var b = document.querySelectorAll('button');
b[0].addEventListener('click', example);
b[1].addEventListener('click', replay);


 var VK={api: function(data, useless, fn){setTimeout(function(){fn(data)}, 3000)}};
```

```html
<button>Call a new Example</button></br>
<button>Replay</button>
<span id="log"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two approaches:

1. Cancel the ongoing request
2. Prevent the callback function from doing work

I have no idea how to do 1. but you can probably ask at the Vkontakte issue tracker https://vk.com/bugs

As for the second one, you can check if the user has already clicked on replay button by the time the response comes back and turn your callback into a noop:

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    VK.api('video.get', { owner_id: 123 }, function (data) {

        // Let's check if user has pressed the replay button and
        // if yes then we abort the function:
        if (userHasPressedReplay) { return; }

        /**...*/ 
    };
});
```

This is not ideal because the request still hits the server... but it prevents execution of the callback function.